# What is my windows 10 password if it never prompts me for a password?

Tags: windows, passwords

I am trying to ssh into my machine over a local connection and its asking for my password.  I have never used my password to login to my machine.  It always asks for a pin.  What am I supposed to enter here?

Windows 10

Comment: Your account absolutely has a password.  If you don’t know your password you can always reset it.  However, if it has a pin, the password is likely the password to your Microsoft Account

Comment: Login to your Microsoft Account (Office if you have has a link). Log in with your PIN and change your password. Keep a record.

Comment: So youre saying that the password to my machine (that I have never set) is going to be my microsoft password?  Ill try it!